# Pandas Dataframe: How to parse integers into string of 0s and 1s?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

print(df)

      sample      column_A         
0     sample1        6/6    
1     sample2        0/4
2     sample3        2/6    
3     sample4       12/14   
4     sample5       15/21   
5     sample6       12/12   
..    ....
```

The values in `column_A` are not fractions, and these data must be manipulated such that I can convert each value into `0s` and `1s` (not convert the integers into their binary counterparts).

The "numerator" above gives the total number of `1s`, while the "denominator" gives the total number of `0s` and `1s` together.

So, the table should actually be in the following format:

```
      sample      column_A         
0     sample1     111111    
1     sample2     0000
2     sample3     110000    
3     sample4     11111111111100    
4     sample5     111111111111111000000 
5     sample6     111111111111  
..    ....
```

I've never parsed an integer to output strings of 0s and 1s like this. How does one do this? Is there a "pandas method" to use with `lambda` expressions? Pythonic string parsing or regex?

Comment: I'd say string parsing, with something like `a,b = map(int, field.split('/')); result = '1'*a + '0'*(b-a)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, suppose you write a function:

```
def to_binary(s):
    n_d = s.split('/')
    n, d = int(n_d[0]), int(n_d[1])
    return '1' * n + '0' * (d - n)
```

So that,

```
>>> to_binary('4/5')
'11110'
```

Now you just need to use [`pandas.Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
 df.column_A.apply(to_binary)
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative:

```
df2 = df['column_A'].str.split('/', expand=True).astype(int)\
                    .assign(ones='1').assign(zeros='0')

df2
Out: 
    0   1 ones zeros
0   6   6    1     0
1   0   4    1     0
2   2   6    1     0
3  12  14    1     0
4  15  21    1     0
5  12  12    1     0

(df2[0] * df2['ones']).str.cat((df2[1]-df2[0])*df2['zeros'])
Out: 
0                   111111
1                     0000
2                   110000
3           11111111111100
4    111111111111111000000
5             111111111111
dtype: object
```

Note: I was actually trying to find a faster alternative thinking apply would be slow but this one turns out to be slower.

Comment: I like this solution, but @AmiTavory had a decent answer before this. I think it may be quicker too, but I haven't check this. I wish I could accept both questions!

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Thank you but you marked this one as correct. I think you meant to mark Ami Tavory's answer (which would be my choice as well).

Comment: It's very interesting question and i do like both answers. Here is my attempt to do it as a one-liner: `df.column_A.str.extract(r'(?P<one>\d+)/(?P<len>\d+)', expand=True).astype(int).apply(lambda x: ['1'] * x.one + ['0'] * (x.len-x.one), axis=1).apply(''.join)` - it will be slower, just wanted to have an one-liner... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternative solutions using [extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [.str.repeat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.repeat.html) methods:

```
In [187]: x = df.column_A.str.extract(r'(?P<ones>\d+)/(?P<len>\d+)', expand=True).astype(int).assign(o='1', z='0')

In [188]: x
Out[188]:
   ones  len  o  z
0     6    6  1  0
1     0    4  1  0
2     2    6  1  0
3    12   14  1  0
4    15   21  1  0
5    12   12  1  0

In [189]: x.o.str.repeat(x.ones) + x.z.str.repeat(x.len-x.ones)
Out[189]:
0                   111111
1                     0000
2                   110000
3           11111111111100
4    111111111111111000000
5             111111111111
dtype: object
```

or a slow (two `apply()`) one-liner:

```
In [190]: %paste
(df.column_A.str.extract(r'(?P<one>\d+)/(?P<len>\d+)', expand=True)
   .astype(int)
   .apply(lambda x: ['1'] * x.one + ['0'] * (x.len-x.one), axis=1)
   .apply(''.join)
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[190]:
0                   111111
1                     0000
2                   110000
3           11111111111100
4    111111111111111000000
5             111111111111
dtype: object
```